# Shell script won't run ruby script file

Tags: shell

My shell script (`my_shell.sh`) won't run the ruby script (`ruby_script_1.rb`) in it.

**`my_shell.sh`**:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Invoke the ruby script here

./ruby_script_1.rb
```

It could not find where the `./ruby_script_1.rb` is, thus errors:

```
# sudo my_shell.sh

: No such file or directory.
```

My ruby script is permission of 777. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a shebang (#!) on the first line of your ruby script?

Comment: 1. Try to use full path to ruby script. 2. Check for hashbang in ruby script. 3. Check permissions on this script: rx and user

Comment: 1. Full path to ruby script: I am already inside the directory where a ruby script resides, not sure why full path is needed.

Comment: 1) I am already in the directory where the ruby script is residing, why the full-path is needed? 2) My ruby script has the following first line: #!/usr/bin/env ruby  3) Permission of ruby script: -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10205 Jul  5 11:37 ruby_script_1.rb

Comment: It looks like your scripts may have CR-NL line endings. Remove the carriage return: use `dos2unix` or `sed 's/\r$//'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Fedora 19, i did little test, sudo uses

```
 Defaults    env_reset
```

and

```
 Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

in few worods, with this two directive, sudo uses his own env variables

commenting this two options in /etc/sudoers and adding my current working directory to my PATH it's work

```
 sudo sudotest.sh 
 + ./ruby.rb
 hello world
```

your directory scripts isn't in the root secure_path